# Viewing/previewing uploaded files in a table/gridview without postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sql-server-2008, gridview, file-upload

I am developing an asp.net application using .NET 4.0

I have a total of 5 fileupload controls in my page.

What I want to do is, as soon as I click on... lets say... 'add file', the added file should be visible at a section of the page in the following format:

```
FileName                 Attached By                     Attached Date
```

When the user clicks on the filelink he should be able to download/preview it.
The files gets saved to the database (I am using sql2008) ONLY after the form is finally submitted and not on click of 'add file'

So as I add more files, the rows with the correct data should be added to the table/grid....

Is there any way of doing this without causing a postback or a DB hit? Code samples will be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible, but only with File API in HTML5
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

This is one File Upload plugin with preview using FileReader API
http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

See the documentation for using with .NET

EDIT:

If you need a solution without using FileReader, you will have to depend on uploading.
You can do as given below:

Step1. User adds a file

Step2. File is uploaded temporarily and content is returned to browser and shown as preview.

Step3. If user accepts the file is added to database and saved permanently

Step4. If user rejects the temporary file is deleted from server.

Comment: This plugin uses FileReader API, which is actually a part of HTML5 specification. It doesn't mean that you have to use HTML5 elements in your page. But preview without uploading will work only in browsers with FileReader support. For example in Safari this plugin shows preview of file only after uploading.

Comment: Oh ok....cool....i'l try it out and see :) my app will be running mostly on IE8 or IE9......